# How can I filter a list of OS files and only return the entries that have a specific extension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.9 and I need to write a function that returns only the names of files ending in "**.zip**" from a list of files? 
What is the most effective way to accomplish this using one or two lines of code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python/42123260

Comment: As posed, this would be answerable with "Yes.". What did you try to do and why did it not work? [ask] & [mre] apply here.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of file types you want and iterate like so:

```
lstFileNames = ['test.txt', 'test.py']
lstOfTypes = ['txt', 'xlsx']
for fileName in lstFileNames: #for each file
    if fileName.split('.')[1] in lstOfTypes: #if the type is what we want
        pass #do some stuff
```

This code would only run the `"do some stuff"` line for `test.txt`

You can also use list comprehensions like so:

```
[fn for fn in lstFileNames if fn.split('.')[1] in lstOfTypes]
```

Comment: `my_list_of_files = ["Sgt.Mnt.Gommerey.txt"]` - you are probably better off using the os module - or at least `.endswith(...)` - tbh you probably should not answer it at all  - due to quality reasons.

Comment: This will not work when the filename contains any `.` other than the one before extension.

Comment: The concise way to do this will be using List Comprehensions. `[file_name for file_name in file_list if name.endswith(".zip")] `

Comment: @kibromhft This can be done with list comps (I updated my answer to include it), but although your version answers the question I like keeping the generality of being able to use any number of file types.